# Dreamweaver alternative to emulate check in/out functionality

Tags: windows, windows-xp, software-rec, dreamweaver, checkout

A little intro: a team of us are updating a website using Dreamweaver. We have no version control, and have to deal with Adobe's software oddities to get things done. I know just how bad this is!

I'm in the minority, in that I only ever edit using the 'Code View' - I never touch the WYSIWYG editor. So we can't yet move to Subversion, Git, or whatever else.

Dreamweaver has functionality that allows you to check in and check out files to indicate when you're working on something. I'm not sure how this works on the server, but I was wondering...

Since Dreamweaver is a glorified FTP client/text editor for me: if I was to use WinSCP (or similar) for FTP and [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (or similar) as a text editor, is there any way for me to indicate to other Dreamweaver users that I've checked out a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check out a file with Dreamweaver, it creates a lock file on the remote server which is just a text file with an LCK extension containing the name and email of the person who checked the file out.

For example, if I check out the file test.txt, a test.txt.LCK file will be placed on the remote server with the following text as its content:

Adam Soltys||asoltys@gmail.com

So you can create the .LCK file manually with your text editor and put it on the server in the same folder as the file you're trying to "check out".

I have to do the same thing now so I'll probably look at producing some sort of script to automate this.